# SWF and Actionscript 3 security

Tags: actionscript

1. How to secure SWF files and Action script 3 code ?
2. mostly while communicating with server side program ?
3. Guide me which is most secure encoding encryption or normal way encryption ? :

I really don't know about these encryption stuffs and all correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a code obfuscator. There are several of them on the internet. The good ones cost money. If you have enough uberness, make your own.
2. Sockets are a tough nut to crack. Also you can use sha or other security protocols, but nothing is 100% safe. Nothing.
3. No such as thing as "most secure". It depends on your needs and nature of your application.

If you don't know about security in IT in general, then don't use Flash, a highly insecure language for whatever you seek to do. Else, expect to be intercepted and either make it not worth the "hacker"'s time to hack apart your stuff, or use lossy techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that you avoid storing important information in the client side,so access tokens, secret passwords or other things that must remain secret one method to avoid this is to call a script on the server side. As mentioned in the other response you can use obfuscation but I noticed that is problematic if you have the project split in libraries.